# Unable to process Xml in pig

Tags: java, xml, apache-pig, hadoop2, bigdata

I am newbie to working in pig. I have encountered an issue while processing XML a file and the below command is what I have used:

```
register '/usr/lib/pig-0.12.0/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar'
pigdata = load '/xml1.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('name') as (doc:chararray);

values = foreach pigdata GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(doc,'<name>(.*)</name>')) AS (name:chararray);

dump values;
```

[image: Screen shot of error encountered]

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be due to file-path issue and/or permissions issue. Can you please check if the hdfs file-path for input file exists at /user/edureka/xml1.xml. Also can you manually check if you are able to create new files in hdfs://localhost:8020/tmp directory etc to rule out permissions issue.